# Google Analytics - Track every property separately

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I'm creating a real estate site, where providers can promote their properties. Since it's nice for providers to see some statistics about clicks, views etc. I tought I use Google Analytics to track this stuff.

In blogger, you can enable Google Analytics and show statistics just for your blog. I'm wondering if it is possible to do it similar for the properties, so that property providers can see separated statistics for each of their properties.

Does Google Analytics have such a functionality? Or is Blogger just an exception because it belongs to Google?

Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options, at least in my mind:

1. Allow the user to input their own account number so that they can get data into their account for just their pages. If you do this, you'll need to make sure that you use different namespaces (see: [tracker names](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApi_gaq#_gaq.push)) in order to allow for this.
2. Create profiles based off of the URL (if your URLs show what provider the property is for.) This is a lot more limited than option 1 because there is a hard limit to the number of profiles you can have and it requires you to manually add individuals to each profile.

If I were you, I'd go for option 1. Option 2 is a "last resort" option in my books, or if it is for very few providers (e.g. just a handful of friends as providers)

Comment: Thanks! Option 1 is the way to go. In Blogger, you can enter an Analytics ID for each of your blogs and you can also do this for your Extensions in the Chrome Web Store, so it doesn't seem to be a bad solution.

Comment: It is becoming more and more common for service-based sites. I'm glad to see you're allowing your users to get analytics data from their content! It's much appreciated ;)